# Trying to remove all entries in a database who have specific query using Carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to delete entries from my table who have are under 17 or minors. And that I want to remove also the parent table.

**so this in my model**

```php
// Define the "age" property accessor.
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return now()->diffInYears($this->birthdate);
}
```

and this is in my controller,

```php
public function removeApplicanWhoAreNotAdults()
{
    $date = Carbon::createFromDate(2001, 01, 01);
    $todaysDate = Carbon::today();

    $lastDay = $date->copy()->endOfYear();

    $applicants = Applicant::whereBetween("birthdate", [$lastDay, $todaysDate])->get();

    $applicants->each(function ($item, $key) {

    });
}
```

Does the code on my controller suffice to the problem I'm trying to solve and How do i query applicants who have ages under 17 for example when my age is null in my db

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you had setup up cascading deletion, you would only need to delete the parent records, and MySQL would automatically remove the child records for you.

Comment: What is `$criminals`? It doesn't seem to be defined in your method Also, what is the relationship name for the "parent" table?

Comment: @RossWilson, How do I query the people who have age of like < 18 when my age is null ?

Comment: When what is `null` sorry? The birthday column??

Comment: no the age column is the null one that 's why I added in the criminalinfo model
```public function getAgeAttribute()
 {
  return now()->diffInYears($this->birthdate);
 }```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution 1:
       $applicant = Applicant::get();
              foreach ($applicant as $key => $value) {
                  $year = now()->diffInYears($value->birthdate);

                  if($year > 17){
                      Applicant::where('id', $value->id)->delete();
                  }
             }
```

Second way is first you have to create one command that way you can create proper programming and good way.

Follow this example

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/example-of-cron-job-in-laravel-5example.html

Put above code in handel() method

```
        public function handle()
        {
          $applicant = Applicant::get();
          foreach ($applicant as $key => $value) {
              $year = now()->diffInYears($value->birthdate);

              if($year > 17){
                  Applicant::where('id', $value->id)->delete();
              }
          }
        }
```